# Why didn't my dupehammer work, when the original tags contains the gold tag?

Tags: support, bug, tags, dupehammer

I voted this question:

[Google App Script filtering Arrays based on Com](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63275568)

as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518). But that didn't close the question immediately. Why? The original set of tags contain a tag [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), that I have a gold badge on. I got the badge recently if that matters. Is there a waiting period  for the hammer to activate after receiving the gold badge?

Comment: possibly a bug: your tags edit in [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63275568/revisions) didn't touch the one where you have gold but system could incorrectly decide that this edit disqualified your dupehammer (though there is also a chance that it simply took more than a hour for system to learn about your new gold badge)

Comment: And congratulations on your new hammer.

Comment: @xdtTransform Thanks. Was hoping to swing it left and right, but my brand new hammer isn't hitting anything.

Comment: Don't swing your hammer near your thumb. Trust me, you'll hit it.

Comment: I'm going to go with: script X that updates dupehammer privileges on SO backend runs every Y hours.

Comment: Dupehammers are born with spawn protection it seems. Gotta wait a bit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is just a caching issue on the backend.

Because there are a few places that can get regularly hit which need your list of tag badges, we don't actually query the live database for your tag badges every single time. Instead, we query that list and then store the results in a local cache for 2 hours. Subsequent requests for the list just pull from the local cache instead of querying again. This is considered an acceptable risk because tag badges are only even awarded once a day in most cases.

Because you tried to use your new gold badge less than an hour after it was awarded, the code was simply looking at stale data at the time. The local cache of your tag badges hadn't updated yet. I see you've since used it to dupehammer a question, so it is working as intended now.